# Rotating axes in 3D for better viewing planes

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, 3d, coordinates

I have this code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    % Generat amb TikZ
    \begin{tikzpicture}
          % Note: the points have coordinates (x,z,y)
          \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
          \coordinate (P0) at (3,2,2);
          \coordinate (P) at (5.5,2,4);

          % Points M i N
          \coordinate (M) at (5.5,2,2);
          \coordinate (N) at (3,2,4);

          % Points of directing vectors

          \coordinate (V1) at (4,2,2);
          \coordinate (V2) at (3,2,3.2);

          % Points of the plane from A, P, M and N
          \coordinate (PLA0) at (2.3,2,0.9);
          \coordinate (PLA1) at (6.5,2,0.9);
          \coordinate (PLA2) at (2.3,2,4.5);
          \coordinate (PLA3) at (6.5,2,4.5);          

          % Coordinate axes
          \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0);
          \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0);
          \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);
          \draw (4,0,0) node[anchor=west] {$x$};
          \draw (0,3,0) node[anchor=south] {$z$};
          \draw (0,0,3) node[anchor=north east] {$y$};

          % Plane
          \fill[color=green!10,thick,draw=black] (PLA0) -- (PLA1) -- (PLA3) -- (PLA2) -- cycle;
          \draw (PLA1) node[anchor=west] {$\pi$};

          % Points: A, P and position vector and AP
          \draw[color=orange,very thick,->,dashed] (O) -- (P0);
          \draw[color=green,very thick,->,dashed] (O) -- (P);
          \draw[color=red,ultra thick,->] (P0) -- (P);
          \draw (P0) node[anchor=south] {$A$};
          \draw (P) node[anchor=south] {$P$};

          % Parallelogram law
          \draw[thick, dotted,->] (P0) -- (M);
          \draw[thick, dotted,->] (P0) -- (N);
          \draw[thick, dotted,->] (M) -- (P);
          \draw[thick, dotted,->] (N) -- (P);         


          % Points M and N and their vectors

          \draw[ultra thick,color=blue,->] (P0) -- (V1);
          \draw[ultra thick,color=blue,->] (P0) -- (V2);
          \draw (M) node[anchor=west] {$M$};
          \draw (N) node[anchor=east] {$N$};



    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Representació de les equacions vectorials d'un pla}
    \label{fig:repr-equacions-vectorials-pla-3d}
\end{figure}
```

and I get this
[image]

But I want to rotate the axis and that my picture seems like this

[image]

Is it possible? I think I have to put something like `\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(240:0.8cm)}, x={(-10:1cm)}, z={(0,1cm)}]`. But I can't imagine how can I do correctly.

Comment: `tikz-3dplot` seems to match your requirement

Comment: Is there a way to do with raw tikz library and not with tikz-3dplot?

Comment: It is about the same thing. All `tikz-3dplot` does is assigning `x=`, `y=`, and `z=` properly. It cannot function without Ti*k*Z, so you can call it a library.

Comment: To rotate around a specific axis you can use `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around y=-10]` and similar for `x` and `z`, is that helpful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on  Torbjørn T. comment:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    % Generat amb TikZ
    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279917/rotating-axes-in-3d-for-better-viewing-planes
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around y=-15, rotate around z=7]
          % Nota: els punts tenen coordenades (x,z,y)
          \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
          \coordinate (P0) at (3,2,2);
          \coordinate (P) at (5.5,2,4);

          % Punts M i N
          \coordinate (M) at (5.5,2,2);
          \coordinate (N) at (3,2,4);

          % Punts dels vectors directors

          \coordinate (V1) at (4,2,2);
          \coordinate (V2) at (3,2,3.2);

          % Punts del pla (a partir de A, P, M i N
          \coordinate (PLA0) at (2.3,2,0.9);
          \coordinate (PLA1) at (6.5,2,0.9);
          \coordinate (PLA2) at (2.3,2,4.5);
          \coordinate (PLA3) at (6.5,2,4.5);          

          % eixos de coordenades
          \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0);
          \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0);
          \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);
          \draw (4,0,0) node[anchor=west] {$x$};
          \draw (0,3,0) node[anchor=south] {$z$};
          \draw (0,0,3) node[anchor=north east] {$y$};

          % Pla
          \fill[color=green!10,thick,draw=black] (PLA0) -- (PLA1) -- (PLA3) -- (PLA2) -- cycle;
          \draw (PLA1) node[anchor=west] {$\pi$};

          % Punts: A, P i vectors de posició i AP
          \draw[color=orange,very thick,->,dashed] (O) -- (P0);
          \draw[color=green,very thick,->,dashed] (O) -- (P);
          \draw[color=red,ultra thick,->] (P0) -- (P);
          \draw (P0) node[anchor=south] {$A$};
          \draw (P) node[anchor=south] {$P$};

          % Llei del paral·lelogram
          \draw[thick, dotted,->] (P0) -- (M);
          \draw[thick, dotted,->] (P0) -- (N);
          \draw[thick, dotted,->] (M) -- (P);
          \draw[thick, dotted,->] (N) -- (P);         


          % Punts M i N i els respectius vectors

          \draw[ultra thick,color=blue,->] (P0) -- (V1);
          \draw[ultra thick,color=blue,->] (P0) -- (V2);
          \draw (M) node[anchor=west] {$M$};
          \draw (N) node[anchor=east] {$N$};



    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Representació de les equacions vectorials d'un pla}
    \label{fig:repr-equacions-vectorials-pla-3d}
\end{figure}
```

With a little balance among `rotate around x=`, `rotate around y=` and `rotate around z=` I will success